# for loop through all folders and execute vbs issue

Tags: windows, batch, script, automation, vbscript

i trying to code a script where it loop through all folders including subfolders however i encounter some errors. It run all *.vbs instead of only Installation.vbs.

In my root folder, i have a folder call confidentialusers.

Inside got 3 sub folders call test1, test2, test3. There are 4 different type of vbs how can i only execute Installation.vbs and ignore the rest of the vbs?

> Test1:Installation.vbs, Uninstallation.vbs, checkstatus.vbs,
> requirement.vbs Test2:Installation.vbs, Uninstallation.vbs,
> checkstatus.vbs, requirement.vbs Test3:Installation.vbs,
> Uninstallation.vbs, checkstatus.vbs, requirement.vbs

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0

for /r confidentialusers %%G IN (installation*.vbs) do cscript /b "%%G"
    
pause
```

Comment: So you want for each sub folders Test1...Test3 run only `Installation.vbs` ?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want for each sub folders `Test1..to..Test3` run only `Installation.vbs`, you should write your batch file as below :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Run Only "Installation.vbs" from each sub folder
pushd "%~dp0"
@for /F "delims=" %%G in ('Dir /S /B "Installation*.vbs"') do cscript /b "%%G"
pause
```

Comment: thank you for your help case solve

Comment: @EugeneNg Please Take a look at this [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour)
Ok Now you have got the privileges to upvote any good question, so don't forget to use it for your future questions and answers ! and you should accept it as answer if this solved your prolem !